# JQuery : Query Builder - How to extract query from code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, query-builder

I am using  [Jquery Query Builder](http://querybuilder.js.org/) in an ASP.net application. Is there a way to extract result query from code behind? Also is there a way to update the filter based on another filter that has been chosen?

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/castle-it/dynamic-linq-query-builder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Plugins page of the link you provided http://querybuilder.js.org/plugins.html:
 you can use .getSQL() method to get at least the WHERE CLAUSE of the sql query built and the .setRulesFromSQL() method to insert additional filters (the second one requires the [SqlParser](https://github.com/mistic100/sql-parser) plug in to work). There is also the [QueryBuilderParser](https://github.com/timgws/QueryBuilderParser) that returns the whole SQL query but it is written in PHP. See if these can help you

Comment: how do you get it from the linq query at the code behind?